Extracting text cells splitted across multiple pages into 1 cell
I am quite new to extracting tabular data in the form of PDFs. I have to use pdfplumber for this task
The PDF file contains feedback comments from students at a university and I need to extract the PDF report using Python. I can extract the comments using the Python library easily, but I'm facing an issue when the table is long and one of the cells is split onto the next page. Attaching a screenshot of the PDF section as I cannot upload the full PDF due to confidentiality.
pdf screenshot cells splitting
Any help in how to detect cells in question will be much appreciated.
I tried playing around with some of the settings, but due to lack of understanding of the library components and time limit on the work, I'm unable to achieve the required outcome.

The RIGHT way to do this is to go back to the data that was used to create the PDF.  Surely it was stored in a database somewhere.  PDF files were never designed to be used as a machine readable database.  You may have to post-process this by hand.

Agree with you 100%. Problem is the data is coming from an outside source and I don't think I can get them to provide access to the database or ask for the data in the form of machine-readable formats.

I have encountered the same problem and had it solved like:

Extract the tables page by page. (I call them first_table and
second_table in your case)

Check if there were any text before second_table by
page.filter(lambda o: o['bottom'] < second_table['top']).extract_text(),
and any text after
first_table by
page.filter(lambda o: o['top'] > first_table['bottom']).extract_text(),
which could confirm the
first_table and second_table were actually parts of a whole table.

Delete the headline of the second_table if the headline of both
tables are the same.

Consider the text at first line of second_table (called
start_text) as a consecutive content of the last line of the
first_table (called end_text) if the end_text doesn't end with
a dot, or the start_text starts with a lower-cased letter.

Join the content of those tables together.


